# Overload Bracket[] operator for a List<object>

Tags: c#, properties, indexer

I'm having some trouble getting an indexer to work with a List of objects. I'd like to be able to access each object in the list by it's name (a string) rather than it's index. So, I'd like to overload the [] operator to achieve this. So far I can't get the overload to show up in intellisense and it does not work at the moment. What I have so far is:

A singleton object of a class called MapInfo:

```
MapInfo mi = MapInfo.Instance;
```

In the MapInfo class I have a list of Table objects:

```
    List<Table> tables;
    public List<Table> Tables
    {
        get { return tables; }
    }
```

And finally in the Tables class I have tried this:

```
class Table : IEnumerable<Table>
{

    public Table this[string tableName]
    {
        get
        {
            foreach (Table table in this)
            {
                if (table.name == tableName)
                    return table;
            }
            return null;
        }
    }
```

I'd like to be able to access my Table objects using:

```
mi.Tables["SomeTableName"]
```

This is the first time I've tried this so I'm not quite sure where I'm going wrong.

Comment: "it does not work at the moment." What is going wrong? Are you getting an error? What is happening that you don't expect?

Comment: Sorry, a bit unclear. The indexer is not being overloaded. I can't see the overload in the intellisense popup and it comes up as a syntax error if I attempt to access the index using the name property.

Comment: `Tables` is a `List<Table>` which does not have a string indexer. It looks like you need to create your own collection type and change the type of `MapInfo.Tables` to return that instead.

Comment: So it's not possible to overload the List<> indexer?

Comment: @T_Bacon - You can overload the indexer, but you need to change the type of `MapInfo.Tables` to be one which has that indexer. You are adding the indexer to the `Table` class but `MapInfo.Tables` is a `List.Table` which does not have such an indexer.

Comment: You cannot overload the List<> indexer because that would require changing the source code of List<>

Comment: Ah, ok... I think I get it. Obviously to overload something it first needs to exist. *bangs head*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use approach like this

```
public class MapInfo {
    private readonly TableCollection _tables = new TableCollection();

    public TableCollection Tables {
        get { return _tables; }
    }
}

public class TableCollection : List<Table> {
    public Table this[string name] {
        get { return this.FirstOrDefault(t => t.Name == name); /*using System.Linq;*/ }
    }
}

public class Table {
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

or simply use a dictionary (`Dictionary<string, Table>`) as Danaldo suggested. but not BOTH of them as he'd coded =))

IMO, the right way is not to use indexers like these, cause as I see there can be more than one table  with 'unique' name in your collections. I'd recommend using a simple List of Tables and a method like GetTableWithName to make things clearer because indexers usually give a (false) hope that that your data is unique

OR you can replace a call to `FirstOrDefault` with `SingleOrDefault` which will internally ensure that if there is an element with the 'name' no other element has the same 'name'

Answer (score 1):

You are overloading the indexer on the Table class. You got something wrong in your code structure. The Table class is an `IEnumerable<Table>`, so a Table contains other Tables.

So, a `List<Table>` will contain Table instances which in turn also contain Table instances.

With `mi.Tables["SomeTableName"]` you are trying to access the indexer of List, not the indexer of Table.

Why not define an indexer in MapInfo?

Answer (score 1):

Use a dictionary

```
Private Dictionary<String, Table> tables;
public Dictionary<String, Table> Tables
{
    get { return tables; }
}
```

Then:

```
class Table : IEnumerable<Table>
{
    public Table this[string tableName]
    {
        get
        {
            Table table;
            if(mi.tables.TryGetValue(tableName, out table))
            {
                return table;
            }
            else
            {
                return null;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your implementation of MapInfo/Table isn't quite right to allow you to do what you want.

Your property of Tables in MapInfo can't be a list of tables, it has to be of type Table. Then your Table class should fully implement the IEnumerable interface.
Quick example written in LinqPad:

```
class Table : IEnumerable<Table>
{
    public Table()
    {
        _tables = new Dictionary<string, Table>();
    }

    public string name { get; set; }
    Dictionary<string, Table> _tables;
    public void Add(string tname)
    {
        _tables.Add(tname, new Table { name = tname });
    }
    public Table this[string tableName]
    {
        get
        {
            Table table;
            if (_tables.TryGetValue(tableName, out table))
                return table;
            return null;
        }
    }


    public IEnumerator<Table> GetEnumerator()
    {
        return _tables.Values.GetEnumerator();
    }

    System.Collections.IEnumerator System.Collections.IEnumerable.GetEnumerator()
    {
        return this.GetEnumerator();
    }
}


void Main()
{
    MapInfo mi = new MapInfo();
    mi.Table["foo"].Dump();
}
class MapInfo
{
    public MapInfo()
    {
        Tables = new Table();
        test();
    }
    private void test()
    {
        Tables.Add("foo");
        Tables.Add("bar");
        Tables.Add("soom");
    }
    public Table Tables { get; set; }
}
```